# How long do I expose Speedball emulsion in my UV light box which is 160 W?

Tags: screen-printing

I just recently bought a UV light box. I’m wondering how long to expose Speedball emulsion in this UV light box. The lights are about 6 inches (~15 cm) from the glass top, so basically the lights are underneath the glass top.

I tried three minutes the other day, and it worked out pretty well, so I’m wondering when I get more detail – with less time or more time? Some of the details didn’t come out too clearly, but I’m just happy it finally worked after trying so many different times and bad emulsion brands. It’s been really hard to figure this out, so thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to answer this because there are too many variables involved. You may want to try doing some tests using an exposure test strip. There's a [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJF3HK2s52w) that explains how.

Comment: Since this is a fixed/controlled setup, this is a case where you should make several small screens of identical size, and then bracket the times: label each one with the exposure time (1 min; 1:30; 2:00: 2:30...etc.) expose them according to the labeled time, then pull a test print, labeling each print with corresponding time exposure. You should then have a good guide for timing based on the current exposure setup. It would be possible to use one screen for this if you have multiple identical artworks, mask all but one and progressively remove a mask every 30 seconds of exposure